# compare tabular data of strings stored in arraylists and join them

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two array lists of strings A and B.
Each has tabular records.

Each entry in arraylist looks like this. The whole line is an entry.

Document: "a","b","c","d","e"

Document: "x","b","r","z","f"

Now if  consider each comma separated entry as a field in table.

Now I have from these two arraylists based on field2 (in first row that would be b) and field 5 , I have two create two new arraylists 1 of all the matching records and one of all the unmatched records.

I am new to java , can not think of a way how to split the data each time and compare both. Please help.

UPDATE: arrayList1, in arrayList2 contains strings. Each string looks like the given example. I have to split the strings in to records. For field2 and field5 I have to match both arraylist. Like sql join I have to show only matching records in an arrayList and unmatched in the other. In new arrays the whole strings should be present.

My arraylists Contain =[ (""b","c","d","e""),("z",c","v","b")......................] now if we split the string in we get fields such as for first row field1=b,field2=c and so on. Two arraylists are similar. Now for these two arraylists for field2 and field5 I need to find out all the records matched and unmatched. for the fields only.... not for the whole strings.

Comment: It is not clear from your description what you want to do. Provide the input and expected output.

Comment: Can you post your source code, right now it is difficult for us to understand your query

Comment: arrayList1, in arrayList2 contains strings.Each string looks like the given example. I have to split the strings in to records. For field2 and field5 I have to match both arraylist. Like sql join I have to show only matching records in an array and unmatched in the other. In new arrays the whole strings should be present.

Comment: @DavidChoweller please see the description.

Comment: @SautripPaul, you do not have the expected output for the given input.

Answer (score 0):

Try `removeAll()`and`retainAll()`

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list1_copy = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line1 = "this is a sample line for trial";
        String line2 = "this is another sample line for test";


        list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(line1.split(" ")));
        list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(line2.split(" ")));
        list1_copy = (ArrayList<String>) list1.clone();
        System.out.println("Original list1: "+list1);
        System.out.println("Original list2: "+list2);

        list1.removeAll(list2);
        System.out.println("Different items in lists: "+list1);

        list1_copy.retainAll(list2);
        System.out.println("Same items in lists: "+list2);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't need to check the whole string for comparing. I need to split the string . The compare the comma separated fields. After separating field2 and field5 need to be matched.

Comment: My arraylists Contain =[ (""b","c","d","e""),("z",c","v","b")......................] now if we split the string we get fields such as for first row field1=b,field2=c and so on. Two arraylists are similar. Now for these two arraylists for field2 and field5 I need to find out all the records matched and unmatched. for the fields only.... not for the whole strings.